# Can AdWords ValueTrack parameters be nested?

Tags: url, google-ads, url-parameters, google-ads-valuetrack

Google provides [ValueTrack](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=enL) as a mechanism for adding dynamic parameters to your advertising URLs.   I have successfully used it for tracking clicks from their search network and content network in separate campaigns:

- `utm_term={keyword}` in a search campaign to pass the keyword the user searched for to my site
- `utm_term={placement}` in a content campaign to passe the site where the ad appeared

If I want want to combine the campaigns, can I somehow combine this tracking?  I see that value track offers `{ifsearch:[value]}` and `{ifcontent:[value]}` options.  Can the keyword and placement be nested inside of them like this?

```
utm_term={ifsearch:{keyword}}{ifcontent:{placement}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [tracking URL required by Infinity](http://www.infinity-tracking.com/support/Full_PPC_Tagging#Google_Ad_Words_tracking_URLs):

```
http://example.com/?infinity=gaw~Campaign~Adgroup~{creative}~{ifsearch:{keyword}}{ifcontent:{placement}}~{matchtype}{ifcontent:c}
```

They are using nested ValueTrack exactly like I was envisioning.   So it can be done!